# How to capture words with letters separated by a consistent symbol in Python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to write a Python regex pattern that will allow me to capture words in a given text that have letters separated by the same symbol or space.

For example, in the text "`This is s u p e r and s.u.p.e.r and super and s!u.p!e.r`", my goal is to extract the words "`s u p e r`", "`s.u.p.e.r`", and `super`. However, I want to exclude "`s!u.p!e.r`" because it does not have the same consistent separating symbol within the word.

I'm currently using the following:

```
x="This is s u p e r and s.u.p.e.r and super and s!u.p!e.r"


pattern = r"(?:\b\w[^\w\d]){2,}"

re.findall(pattern, x)


['s u p e r ', 's.u.p.e.r ', 'super ', 's!u.p!e.']
```

I'm just curious if it's possible to exclude the cases that do not have the same symbol.

Comment: `pattern = r"(?<!\S)\w(?=(\W))(?:\1\w)+(?!\S)"` might work. But only with `re.finditer`. See https://ideone.com/0fnzUl

Comment: Just a word of caution: such a filter will disallow messages like `r'n'b`, `I 3 U` and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using

```py
pattern = r"(?<!\S)\w(?=(\W))(?:\1\w)+(?!\S)"
results = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(pattern, x)]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/0fnzUl) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bwWTrh/2).

```py
import re
x="This is s u p e r and s.u.p.e.r and super and s!u.p!e.r"
pattern = r"(?<!\S)\w(?=(\W))(?:\1\w)+(?!\S)"
print([m.group() for m in re.finditer(pattern, x)])
# => ['s u p e r', 's.u.p.e.r', 'super']
```

*Pattern details*

- `(?<!\S)` - left-hand whitespace boundary
- `\w` - a word char
- `(?=(\W))` - a positive lookahead that requires the next char to e a non-word char capturing it into Group 1 (`\1`)
- `(?:\1\w)+` - one or more repetitions of the same char as captured in Group 1 and then a single word char
- `(?!\S)` - right-hand whitespace boundary

Answer (score 3):

As you want to match at least 2 word characters, you can capture a first and a last one with a single capture group `(\W)` in between.

Then optionally repeat matching a single word char followed by a backreference `\1` to the same captured char:

```
(?<!\S)\w(\W)(?:\w\1)*\w(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitspace boundary to the left (because using `\b` will give you partial word matches)
- `\w(\W)` match a single word char, and capture a single word char except for a digit in **group 1**
- `(?:\w\1)*` Optionally repeat matching a single word char and a backreference to group 1
- `\w(?!\S)` Match a single word char followed by a whitespace boundary to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U3XFfc/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ovZwsu).

As this part `(\W)` is captured in group 1, you would have to use *re.finditer* to get the full matches because using *re.findall* will return only the group 1 value.